# Browser simulation - Python 3

Tags: python, session, browser, cookies

I need to access a few HTML pages through a Python 3 script, problem is that I need COOKIE functionality, therefore a simple urllib HTTP request won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python3's urllib has cookie support, look at [urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/urllib.request.html), and [http.cookiejar](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/http.cookiejar.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use [**requests**](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests).

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/requests-is/awesome'
>>> r = requests.get(url)

>>> print r.cookies
{'requests-is': 'awesome'}
```

*Reference: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies*

As of a few days ago, [requests supports Python 3](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/70), though you might have to use one of the `develop` branches, not entirely sure about the status of upstream integration.